# Adding a css attribute to an asp element using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making an alert using ASP.NET and C# and I would like to change the CSS styling of an ASP.Net element based on the the type of message am passing to the element e.g green label for positive alert or red label for negative alert.

ive using  tried `Label1.Style.add()` with not success

Comment: try to set in `PreInit` event

Comment: that should have done the trick

Comment: Am afraid i don't know what you mean by preInt

Comment: @Sibusiso Shongwe : Post the sample code that you have tried to achieve this functionality. For information about `PreInit` event refer this  [Page Life Event for Asp.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Label1.Stye.Add("color", "red")
```

The first parameter being the css attribute you want to add, and the second being its value.

Comment: Are you talking to yourself? Or this is the solution you looking for.

Comment: That would be the solution, I answered my own question